which one, /dev/sdaX or /dev/nvme0n0p1 script should i use for grub?
Currently i'm stuck in grub script for dual booting chromeOS provided by guide to install chromeOS since it's freezing during boot
here's the script provided by the video guide, and here's the partition i got from my laptop. my laptop got 2 ssd, the first ssd divided into 2 partition (c,d letter), and the 2nd ssd also divided into 2 partition (e,f letter), and chromeOS installed in f letter.
since chrome based in linux some people said i've should use /dev/nvme0n0p1 instead /dev/sdaX based on the original script guide.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
